# Dll reference of one project into another project

Tags: c#, vb.net, dll, namespaces, reference

I have 2 projects, one built in VB.NET and another in C#.NET. I want to use certain functionality of VB.NET into C#.NET and hence I have added the dll file of VB.NET solution into C#.NET as a reference by browsing the dll from my system.

Say dll name for VB.NET is myData.dll

In my C#.NET project I am trying to declare it as a namespace i.e. "using myData;" and its giving me an error of "Type or namespace name could not be found"

Am I missing something??

Comment: Did you add a reference to myData.dll in your C# project?

Comment: Yes I did add it as a reference in my C# project and the class is set to public in VB.NET

Comment: There really isn't enough information here to answer the question. We can just guess at possible solutions, and I don't think those qualify to be posted as answers. Remember that VB.NET projects have a project-level namespace that you can find in the project Properties. The namespace specified there will be pre-pended to any `Namespace` declarations you have in your code file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A clue about how your VB.NET project is organized. There are some things that can go wrong and you obviously are not aware of them, so lets find out.

According to our information the dll is added as reference.

> Say dll name for VB.NET is myData.dll

Ok, so that is the DLL and you reference it.

> declare it as a namespace i.e. `using myData;`

No, you do NOT declare "it as a namespace". You tell the compiler to also look in this namespace for classes. Now, you do NOT tell to compiler whether myData.dll actually contains the namespace `myData`. This is a totally different thing. You can do without `using` - if you prefix every class. Nothing in the using statement references a dll.

It could be VB.NET has wrapped another namespace around and it is `myData.myData`. No joke. It could also be you forgot to make the classes public.

To find out:

- Open the DLL using Object Browser ("View", "ObjectBrowser") and look what namespace and classes are in the DLL.
- Go and look for the class you want to use and see what it says there. You may be surprised about the classes and / or the namespace.

Comment: Yes this worked... I added the namespace of the dll and I was able to create an object for the class... Another issue am facing now is with the object I have declared, am not able to call the function inside the class, even if the fucntion is declared as public...

Comment: Another issue, another question ;) VB.NET is sort of famous for maling up namespaces in a hidden way.

Comment: Yeah another question... :) But why isn't it calling any of the functions in the class? :(

Comment: Hmm, I don't think it's accurate to say that the way VB.NET generates namespaces is in any way hidden or confusing. Although I accept this was probably tongue-in-check, it's worth spelling out here for clarity. The trick is that every namespace declared in your code files is prefixed by the namespace specified in the project properties. So, whereas in C#, you could wrap a class with `namespace Foo` and it would be in namespace `Foo`, in VB.NET, it would be in `MyApplication.Foo` (where `MyApplication` is the namespace declared in your project's properties).

Comment: That prettym uch sums it up. C# has no "master" namespace - the one you set in project properties is just used fror new class files s dfault. All namespace declaration is in the code. For VB.NET - the one set in the proejct properties is always added to your declarations, so classesi n that namespace should not hae any in code namespace declaration.

Comment: Once you understand it, it is fairly simple, but any time I have to create a new VB project, I always blank out the project namespace and just use the Namespace statement.