# Use DLL from another project

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I have a website project and a class library project beside each other in Visual Studio (c#), the class library is added as a reference project to the website. If I add a new dll (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel) to the class library project I can use it within that project but how can I call it from the website project?

I have tried adding it to the website project >> right click add reference but it doesn't seem to be available (even after building it), so am trying this method.

Comment: You'll have to refer all the libraries in your `website` project if you want to use them in there. If you're just using them inside your `library`, then your website will not require their reference.

Comment: Similar http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5779206/dll-reference-of-one-project-into-another-project

Comment: When I click on the DLL it doenst have a namespace, is it suppose to/can I give it one?